# Simplest Fortran Code Still Has an Error

Tags: fortran

I'm learning Fortran for a new job and started writing some very, very basic programs. To compile, I'm using gcc version 4.6.2, and I'm working on Linux Suse OS (if that matters at all). I *believe* the version of Fortran I'm using is F90 or F95. The code is written using the VIM text editor.

Here is the program I've written

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: x = 2, y = 3
INTEGER            :: z = x+y

print *, z
```

That's it! Oh, and the lines are indented, They start on column 8, so indentation isn't an issue.

UPDATE 1
I have tried doing this like so:

```
PROGRAM print_stuff
        print *, z
END PROGRAM print_stuff
```

I also tried adding the IMPLICIT NONE statement to all of that and didn't get a change in the error.
END UPDATE 1

I save, quit, and compile. The compiler returns this error:

```
Error: Unexpected end of file in 'practice1.f'
```

Anyone know what the problem is? I've even tried removing the print statement and just having the variable declarations but the same error occurs. It's keeping me from practicing Fortran at all!

Comment: just for fun the minimum fortran file you can compile is just the single line "end".  Seriously is is possible you are failing to put a CR on the last line? (Though my compiler doesnt need it, i suppose some might)

Comment: Are you compiling with `gcc` or `gfortran`?

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you are saving your file as `*.f`, then are you padding your lines of code with 7 or 8 spaces? Does changing the file name to `practice1.f90` allow you to compile?

Comment: Ok, so I realized just how little I know about Fortran today. The problem was that I wasn't declaring the variables inside the program. For some reason I thought it was ok to declare them in the very first lines of code and then start the program.

Also, I'm using gfortran (now). Again, I know very little about this and didn't realize right away that gcc is for compiling C.

I'm saving as .f and padding with 7 spaces. I'll save as .f90 from now on since apparently that's the best practice for writing in Fortran90

Comment: Aha.  The order in which statements may appear in a Fortran program (or other *compilation unit*) is mandated by the language standard(s).  See http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-93B97D88-B658-4016-8F95-6267621C579C.htm for an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Your first version

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: x = 2, y = 3
INTEGER            :: z = x+y

print *, z
```

is NOT a valid Fortran program.  Every valid program ends with the `end` statement.  A 'program' without an `end` statement is not syntactically correct. Keep reading your introductory tutorial.

I suggest you get into the habit of starting your programs with a program statement, with a name, such as

```
program myprog
```

and ending them with

```
end program myprog
```

Strictly, neither the `program` statement nor a program name is necessary but they do make things look a bit more comprehensible.

Oh, and while I'm writing ... don't get into the habit of starting lines at column 8, that smacks of the now out-dated fixed-form source.  If you are using a reasonable compiler (such as `gcc`) give your filenames the `.f90` suffix and let your source code run free.  All the while observing good habits of indentation of course.

*EDIT* in response to OP's edits

```
PROGRAM print_stuff
        print *, z
END PROGRAM print_stuff
```

and

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: x = 2, y = 3
INTEGER            :: z = x+y

print *, z
END
```

are both syntactically correct.  Both `gfortran` (v4.1.2) and Intel Fortran (v13.0.1) compile both correctly and produce executables which execute.

Comment: Well I tried that as well. For instance I wrote:

PROGRAM print_stuff
   print *, z
END PROGRAM print_stuff

I also tried using the IMPLICIT NONE statement (and not using it) and just compiling the variable declarations and not having a print statement at all. Same errors in all cases.

Comment: Don't put code into comments if you want people to read it.  Edit your question.